# How to Upgrade Raspbian OS 4.14 to 4.19 via terminal

Tags: raspberry-pi, upgrade, raspbian

For a project, I need functionality to upgrade Raspian OS(old version) to the latest version(4.19 for now) remotely. How to do that with python program?

I attached my Python code I tried. But it upgrades only Raspian 4.14 release to the latest version(4.14.37 to 4.14.71)
Any help would be greatly appreciated..Thanks in advance

```
import os

os.system("sudo apt update")
os.system("sudo apt dist-upgrade")
os.system("sudo apt clean")
os.system("sudo reboot")
```

Comment: This isn't python related